# PostgreSQL index scan

Tags: postgresql

I have table with following index:

```
celltick_db=> \d+ MTSMSes
                                                          Table "hangman.mtsmses"
  Column  |            Type             |                         Modifiers                         | Storage  | Stats target | Description
----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 eventid  | integer                     | not null default nextval('mtsmses_eventid_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 methodid | character varying(63)       | not null                                                  | extended |              |
 moid     | integer                     | not null                                                  | plain    |              |
 phone    | character varying(15)       | not null                                                  | extended |              |
 text     | character varying(511)      | not null                                                  | extended |              |
 ts       | timestamp without time zone | default now()                                             | plain    |              |
```

**Indexes:**
    "mtsmses_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (methodid, eventid)

when running following SQL, it running with index scan:

```
celltick_db=> explain SELECT methodId, 
moId, phone, text, eventId 
FROM MTSMSes 
where  methodId='INTERACTIVE_REQUEST'  and eventid>18606263;  



                                                                                                                                  QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using mtsmses_pkey on mtsmses  (cost=0.56..3350.24 rows=1856 width=172)
   Index Cond: (((methodid)::text = 'INTERACTIVE_REQUEST'::text) AND (eventid > 18606263))
```

but when running as below, it making seq. scan:

```
celltick_db=> explain SELECT methodId, moId, 
phone, text, eventId FROM MTSMSes where  methodId='INTERACTIVE_REQUEST'  
and eventid>(SELECT lastFetchedEventId FROM MTSMSesConsumers WHERE 
 methodId='INTERACTIVE_REQUEST');
                                                  QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on mtsmses  (cost=21.07..769488.62 rows=6188057 width=172)
   Filter: ((eventid > $0) AND ((methodid)::text = 'INTERACTIVE_REQUEST'::text))
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Scan using mtsmsesconsumers_methodid_key on mtsmsesconsumers  (cost=0.26..21.07 rows=1 width=4)
           Index Cond: ((methodid)::text = 'INTERACTIVE_REQUEST'::text)
```

I advise using the "where clause". can you please advice if there is any parameter that I should change (I tried to set enable_bitmapscan=on, but no help).

there you have the explain:

```
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on mtsmses  (cost=21.07..769488.62 rows=6188057 width=172) (actual time=562634.438..1357306.944 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: ((eventid > $0) AND ((methodid)::text = 'INTERACTIVE_REQUEST'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 18606173
   Buffers: shared hit=328975 read=162034
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Scan using mtsmsesconsumers_methodid_key on mtsmsesconsumers  (cost=0.26..21.07 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.231..0.275 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: ((methodid)::text = 'INTERACTIVE_REQUEST'::text)
           Buffers: shared hit=4
 Total runtime: 1357309.108 ms
```

at mtsmses, I have only one methodid:

```
celltick_db=> select count(distinct methodid) from mtsmses;
 count
-------
     1
```

my postgres running - random_page_cost=4.

for now, I think the best way is to delete old data from the table.

Comment: In the second query, the optimizer can't infer the potential advantage of an index scan, because it doesn't know the value that the sub-select returns. The choice for an index is based on the column statistics and the input value. If the input value is dynamic, the optimizer can't evaluate that (because the value will only be know once the query is run).

Comment: Unrelated, but: the primary key `methodid, eventid` looks strange when `methoid` is generated from a sequence and thus won't contain duplicates in the first place

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? With 15 Million rows and 1000 distinct methodids I get the following plan in Postgres 10: https://explain.depesz.com/s/y5n which is only slightly slower than the plan with a hardcoded value for eventid: https://explain.depesz.com/s/gE7g

Comment: hi, I have the following:
celltick_db=> select count(distinct eventid ) from mtsmses;
  count
----------
 18606175
(1 row)
using postgres - 9.3.9

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Postgres 10 or Postgres 9.3 (see here for the 9.3 plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/LzT). Does running `analyze mtsmses;` change anything in the plan?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: What is the value of `random_page_cost` (you can check using `show random_page_cost`) . If that is too high, the planner will usually favour a Seq Scan over an index scan. You could try reducing that value to make the planner prefer an index scan. My computer has a SSD, so I have set `random_page_cost` to `1` that's probably the reason why I get the good plans

Comment: You can change `random_page_cost` for your session and see if a query using an index scan is indeed faster. You do not need any DBA privileges for that